# Key error u'True when checking for a value in JSON dump stored in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, robotframework, keyerror

I have piece of code that retrieves the a JSON dump from a location and check for values in the stored dictionary.

My JSON dump looks like this:

```
{
    u'response': {
        u'username': u'robo',
        u'first_name': u'robot-update',
        u'last_name': u'frmwrk-update',
        u'is_deleted': False,
        u'entity_type': u'user',
        u'admin': True,
        u'image': {
            u'complete_json': True,
            u'entity_type': u'image',
            u'original': u'/images/default-user-icon.png',
            u'icon': u'/images/default-user-icon.png'
        },
        u'title': u'update-title',
        u'email': u'robotupdate@robot.com',
        u'dept': u'update-department',
        u'subscribed_to_emails': True,
        u'notes': u'update-note',
        u'complete_json': True,
        u'id': 177,
        u'tags': [],
        u'developer': True
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve a key value pair and compare it with my expected value.

My code snippet is as follows user_info gets back my json dumps:

```
    def check_user_info(self, user_name, key_value, expected_value):
        logger.info("Checking to see if the - {0} is the same as the expected value       {1}...".format(field_value, expected_value))
        user_info = self.my_api.get_user_info(self.token, self.app_address, user_name)
        logger.console("json dumps------ {0}".format(user_info))
        logger.console("the check value is-- {0}".format(user_info['response'][field_value]))
        check_value = user_info['response'][field_value]
        logger.info("field value is {0}".format(user_info['response'][field_value]))
        if check_value == expected_value:
            logger.info("The test value {0} is the same as expected value  {1}".format(check_value, expected_value))
```

When I try to look up the values for first name, last name or email. I get through the method. But when I try to get the admin value I get a keyerror u'True

Please kindly let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. Can you expand your code snippet?

Comment: user_info = self.my_api.get_user_info(self.token, self.app_address, user_name)

Comment: Andy-- Please see the edited code in the question. I have given out the full method

Comment: Your code uses `field_valuw`, but nowhere do you set `field_value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule of debugging is to assume that the error message is telling you the truth. In this case it is telling you `keyerror u'True`.

This means that somewhere in your code you're doing the equivalent of `some_dictionary[u'True']`. In the code you posted, there is nothing that is using the literal value `True` as a key, so it must be in a variable.  Since you didn't post the actual error, I have to guess which line is causing the error.

Most likely, the error is coming from this code: `user_info['response'][field_value])`. That means that `field_value` is likely `u'True'`. The question now becomes, *why* is it true? Since your code doesn't show where that value comes from, there's no way I can answer that. You'll have to do some additional debugging where you set that variable.

Looking at the name of the variable, it appears you're expecting the variable to contain a *value*, but you're using it as a *key*. Perhaps that is the problem? Maybe that line of code should be `user_info['response'][user_name]` (ie: replace `key_value` with `user_name`)?

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your code raises a `NameError` on `field_value`, so I assume it's not your real code. Now given the error *you* get, it looks like you're trying to use `u'True'` as the `key_value` (which will of course raise a `KeyError`) instead of the `expected_value`.